# Android and sockets - CorruptedStreamException

Tags: android, sockets

I'm writing a small app that's supposed to mirror moves made on another phone during a game of tetris. It works perfectly for a little while, untill i get a CorruptedStreamException on the server side while writing an object.

Here's the code for the server:

```
public void run() {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        s = ss.accept();
        Log.i(TAG,"accepted");
        oos.flush();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        while(run){
            busy=true;
            oos.writeObject(positions);
            busy = false;
            this.sleep(100);
            oos.reset();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{//close sockets!!
    try{
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

I'll toss out the client side code too:

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c = null;
    Socket s = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "it entered try");
        s = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        oos.flush();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        Log.i("try","has connected");
        while(run){
            blockList=(ArrayList<Posision>)ois.readObject();
            if(blockList!=null){
                try{
                    c=mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized(mSurfaceHolder){
                        mTetrisView.drawTetris(c, blockList);
                    }
                }finally{
                    if(c!=null){
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (EOFException ez){
        Log.i("catch", "End of file");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("catch",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{//close socket!!
        try{
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            s.close();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

And a stack trace might come in handy too, when thinking of it:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1712)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1665)
at com.prosjekt.tetris2.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:42)
```

Now why am I getting this error? As far as I know, writeObject() shouldn't be able to throw it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how I figured this out, but turns out that the client thread didn't print the errors it got (this however, doesn't explain why the server side threw the corruptedStreamException). The fault lay with the client getting a OptionalDataException with the length field set to 0 (indicates end of stream). I knew for a fact that the writeObject were called often enough that this shouldn't be a problem, so I decided to rewrite part of the code. 
The final fix is really too simple, and this is how my while loop at server side looked like after rewriting:

```
while(run){
    oos.writeObject(new ArrayList<Posisions>(positions));
    oos.flush();
}
```

There's viritually no changes to the client side, so I guess the rate of resets() somehow stomped the stream.